# ring of fractions of a ring of fractions, reasoning verification

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I have done the following reasoning, and i want to know if it is correct.

Let $R$ be an integral domain. Let $S$ and $T$ be two multiplicatively closed subsets of $R$, with $S\subseteq T$. Let consider $S^{-1}R$ and put $\bar{T}:=\{ \frac{a}{1}\in S^{-1}R\mid a\in T\}$. Then $\bar{T}$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $S^{-1}R$. Let consider $\bar{T}^{-1}(S^{-1}R)$. The typical element is of the form $$\frac{\frac{a}{s}}{\frac{b}{1}}$$ with $a\in R$, $s\in S$, $b\in T$. Let consider the map $$f\colon \frac{\frac{a}{s}}{\frac{b}{1}}\in \bar{T}^{-1}(S^{-1}R) \mapsto \frac{a}{bs}\in T^{-1}R$$
I have showed that $f$ is well defined and it is an isomorphism of commutative rings.

Are these things possible? Or may have i proved something false? Can this result be further generelized? Can you give me references or books in wich this argument is discussed? I want to study in deep this topic.

Comment: This seems to be straight out of Chapter 3 of _Commutative Algebra_ by Atiyah, MacDonald.